# Compute areas for multiple entries of GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, osmnx

I have some working code that computes the area of a city by name:

```
def get_area_of_city(city_name):
    # Fetch the geodataframe for the specified city
    city_gdf = ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(city_name, which_result=1)

    # Access the geometry (polygon) of the city from the geodataframe
    city_polygon = city_gdf['geometry']

    # Get the latitude and longitude of the city (centroid of the polygon)
    city_latitude, city_longitude = city_polygon.geometry.centroid.y, city_polygon.geometry.centroid.x

    # Define the Cylindrical Equal Area (CEA) projection centered at the city
    cea_projection = f"+proj=cea +lon_0={city_longitude} +lat_ts={city_latitude} +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

    # Reproject the polygon to the CEA projection
    city_polygon_cea = city_polygon.to_crs(cea_projection)

    # Compute the area of the polygon in square meters
    area_square_meters = city_polygon_cea.area

    # You can also convert the area to square kilometers if needed
    area_square_kilometers = area_square_meters / 1000000.0
    
    return area_square_kilometers
```

Now, I want to adapt this code such that it works with any `GeoDataFrame` that contains multiple cities. This code should be able to construct a projection for each city and apply it to the polygon to get the area. How can I do this? I currently have the following code:

```
def get_area_of_geodataframe(gdf):
    # Get a copy of the original GeoDataFrame
    gdf_copy = gdf.copy()

    # Get the latitude and longitude of the centroid of all geometries in the GeoDataFrame
    gdf_copy['city_latitude'] = gdf_copy.geometry.centroid.y
    gdf_copy['city_longitude'] = gdf_copy.geometry.centroid.x

    # Define the Cylindrical Equal Area (CEA) projection for each geometry
    gdf_copy['cea_projection'] = gdf_copy.apply(lambda row: f"+proj=cea +lon_0={row['city_longitude']} +lat_ts={row['city_latitude']} +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", axis=1)

    # Reproject each geometry to the CEA projection
    gdf_copy['city_polygon_cea'] = gdf_copy.apply(lambda row: row.to_crs(row['cea_projection']), axis=1)

    # Compute the area of each geometry in square meters
    gdf_copy['area_square_meters'] = gdf_copy['city_polygon_cea'].area

    # Convert the area to square kilometers
    gdf_copy['area_square_kilometers'] = gdf_copy['area_square_meters'] / 1000000.0

    # Drop the intermediate columns and return the modified GeoDataFrame
    gdf_copy = gdf_copy.drop(columns=['city_latitude', 'city_longitude', 'cea_projection', 'city_polygon_cea'])
    return gdf_copy
```

However, the error I revieve is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_crs'` when I call `row.to_crs()`.

How do I have to adapt my code?

I tried to use the above code, but I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is it not working?

Surprisingly or not, when you take a single row of a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`, it ends up being a `pandas.Series`, thus it does not have the method `to_crs()`.

```py
type(gdf_copy.iloc[0])

# returns <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

There seems to be a debate [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/136) on whether or not getting back a `pandas.Series` should be the expected behavior. [This answer](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/136#issuecomment-804009335) provides an interesting indexing trick (notice the double square-brackets):

```py
type(gdf_copy.iloc[[0]])

# returns <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
```

I don't think we can make use of that trick here though, as `apply()` let us work with what is already a `pandas.Series`.

Should you really want to go that way, you could probably accomplish that by working directly with [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) and [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/).

## Why might it not be a good idea anyway?

Had it worked the way you were trying to, you would have ended up with shapely objects with different CRS in a single geometry column, which `geopandas` does not support. You can have different geometry columns with different CRS though, despite the fact that only one is considered as the *main* geometry of the GeoDataFrame.

## Suggested way to go...

Why not reuse your nice and working `get_area_of_city(city_name)` function?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Lyon', 'Paris', 'Marseille']})
df['area_square_kilometers'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_area_of_city(row['city']), axis=1)

#        city  area_square_kilometers
# 0       Lyon               47.985400
# 1      Paris              105.390441
# 2  Marseille              242.129201
```

Hope this helps!